# Pass Entity Framework type to generic method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my project using Entity Framework, I have a bunch of functions that look almost exactly alike, so I want to created a generic method they call:

```cs
private IHttpActionResult GetData<TEntity>(DbSet<TEntity> data)
```

The problem I'm having is that the `data` parameter is saying `TEntity` has to be a reference type to work, but the type of the entity comes from auto-generated code that doesn't have any base class that I can constrain via a `where` clause on the method definition.

I'd basically want to call it by getting a context and passing the table in like so:

```cs
using (var context = new DataModel.MyEntities()) {
    GetData(context.Lab_SubSpace_Contact);
}
```

Comment: `private IHttpActionResult GetData<TEntity>(DbSet<TEntity> data) where TEntity : class`  <=== Why can't you do that?

Comment: When it says the `TEntity` has to be a reference type it means that as an unconstrained generic type it can be either a reference or a value type.  Igor has given you the constraint that will limit the generic type to a reference types `class`.

Comment: Cause I didn't realize I could just do that :)  It won't let me accept your answer for 9 more minutes.  Thanks for the quick solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on [@Igor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49309913/2141621), you don't have to pass the `DbSet<TEntity>`, you can also get that dynamically through the type parameter:

```
private IHttpActionResult GetData<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
    using (var context = new YourContext())
    {
        var dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very cool!  This definitely makes the DB connection cleaner too.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a base class, you only have to specify a constraint that it has to be a class (not a struct). This can be done with `where TEntity : class`

[Constraints on Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

> `where T : class` : The type argument must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.

Modified code

```
private IHttpActionResult GetData<TEntity>(DbSet<TEntity> data) where TEntity : class
```